# Creating a Razor like syntax in a VSC Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create a Visual Studio Code extension that highlights code in a similar way to how Razor works. Instead of HTML it uses 6502 assembler as the language.

I have the following in my `tmLanguage.json`.

```json
"patterns":
  [
    {
        "include" : "source.asm"
    },
    {
        "name" : "meta.embedded.block.asm",
        "begin": "@{",
        "end": "}",
        "beginCaptures": { "0": { "name" : "punctuation.curlybrace.transition.asm"}},
        "endCaptures": { "0": { "name" : "punctuation.curlybrace.transition.asm"}},
        "patterns" :
        [
            { "include" : "source.asm" },
            { "include" : "source.cs" }
        ]
    }
  ]
```

The normal asm highlighting is working, as well as the first layer within in the `@{ }` block. However any code in further curly braces doesn't have the syntax applied.

An example of the output can be seen here: (note how the `lda` is white within the method. the inspector shows this as a c# variable, not a keyword like elsewhere.)

[image: example]

Obviously `source.cs` has some brace matching, so I guess I need to override that or modify it someway?